# How find coefficients that minimize the function output?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a model that predicts output (1 or 0). The goal is to minimize the error, so absolute value of difference between predicted and observed values should be close to 0 as much as possible. `mod_7` dataset shows my initial dataset without filtering by specific columns. My code is inspired by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090791/how-do-i-optimize-and-find-the-coefficients-for-two-equations-simultaneously-in)

I dont know why but values in `best_fit`  are always the same as in `first_guess` (even if i change `first_guess`  values)

Could you help t identify why I have this problem?

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
mod_7 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,size=(100, 5)), columns=['IsCar', 'Is10places', 'observed_value','hybrid_score', 'col_score'])


def fuel_efficiency_grade_calculator(df):
    df['total_score_adj'] = np.where(df['hybrid_score'] == 1, df['total_score'] + 1 , df['total_score'] - 1)
    return df


def func(params):
    app_coef, ext_coef = params

    df_temp = mod_7[(mod_7['IsCar'] != 1) & (mod_7['Is10places'] == 1)]
    df_temp['total_score'] = 0.55 + app_coef * df_temp["hybrid_score"] + ext_coef * df_temp["col_score"]

    # compute grades
    df_temp = fuel_efficiency_grade_calculator(df_temp)  # this function does some data transfromation, but the final goal is compute column df_temp['fuel_efficient']
    df_temp['predicted_value'] = np.where(df_temp['total_score_adj'] >= 7, 1, 0)

    return abs(sum(df_temp['predicted_value'] - df_temp['observed_value']))


# choose reasonable values for your 7 parameters here,
# i.e. close to the "right" answer, this may take a few tries
first_guess = [3, 5]

# here we run the minimisation
res = minimize(func, first_guess)

# this is an array of your best fit values for a1-a7
best_fit = res.x
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. please include all data and functions such that we can copy-paste your code snippet. Otherwise, it's hard to help properly.

Comment: what does `func(first_guess)` produce?

Comment: @joni made a reproducible example

Comment: @hpaulj as i took it from another example, I only can say my thinking of it. It is some random random which you assume to be a true value (and without this parameter minimise() function does not work)

Comment: no, I want you to test it.

Comment: @hpaulj Out[134]: 2

Comment: When I run your code, even just the `func([3,5])` I get `pandas` warnings, `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`  I know `numpy` better than `pandas`, so don't offhand know what this is about.  But I wonder, do you really need to modify the dataframe in `func`?  Can't you do this calculation with the `values` arrays derived from the columns?

Comment: When do `func([3.2,5.1])` I get the same result `2`.  Even for bigger changes it's still `2`.  `minimize` starts with the first guess, and tweaks the values just a bit, looking for changes that reduce the result.  If the result doesn't change for small changes, its going to settle on that first_guess.  Your `func` has to make sense for small changes in the inputs.